# cocos2d-x background music's volume cannot change

Tags: cocos2d-x

When I use cocos2d-x to write a program, I found I could not change the volume of the music. Neither in the demo. So I open the source file. I found that the function setBackgroundMusicVolume is empty, and the function `getBackgroundMusicVolume` just return 1.0f.
I want to know why. The code is showed below:

```
float SimpleAudioEngine::getBackgroundMusicVolume()
{
    return 1.0;
}

void SimpleAudioEngine::setBackgroundMusicVolume(float volume)
{
}

float SimpleAudioEngine::getEffectsVolume()
{
    return 1.0;
}

void SimpleAudioEngine::setEffectsVolume(float volume)
{
}
```

Comment: It works on last stable cocos2d-x v2. What the version do you use?

Comment: cocos2d-x 2.04. I have seen the source file in cocos2d-x2.14, it is the same@vedi

Answer (score 1):

Set Background Music Volume Effect

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(1.0);
```

Comment: Volume value in 0.0 to 1.0 also float

Answer (score 0):

What platform you are looking at?
Different platform will have their own implementation; You can see those implementation in "CocosDenshion" folder accordingly.